# Using SUM() on ENUM column with negative numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to restrict the value in the column "voteValue" to either -1 or 1, so I used an ENUM data type for this. However, when I try to calculate the total value of the votes (that is, +1 votes and -1 votes), I end up getting +2 for each -1 vote instead of subtraction.

I know I can just divide this to 2 different SQL codes to get the SUMS of +1 and -1 votes separately, but I want my code to be as simple as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is tis a yes/no type situation that you're capturing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUM should not be used on ENUMs. Internally they are using integer values. But you should not use it for counting those numbers. 
You can `group by` the `enum` column and use `count()` on other columns to get how many votes per enum is casted.

See the following scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE `votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote` enum('PARTY_2','PARTY_1','PARTY_9') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into votes( user, vote) values( 1, 2), (2, 3), (4,3), (3, 1), (6,1), (5,2), (8, 2), (9,3);

SELECT vote `Party`, count(id) as `Votes`  FROM votes group by `vote`;
```

#### Output

```
+---------+-------+
| Party   | Votes |
+---------+-------+
| PARTY_2 |     2 |
| PARTY_1 |     3 |
| PARTY_9 |     3 |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want both on the same row you'll need a CASE statement.  Something like this *should* work

```
select sum(case when voteValue = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as positiveVoteTotal,
           sum(case when voteValue = -1 then 1 else 0 end) as negativeVoteTotal
from leTable
```

I think you would be better off representing vote as a nullable bit/boolean type though (you could use same technique to query)